# Video Capture broken in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to capture video on my app, but nothing happens (i.e the record window doesnt open), tested on older version of iOS and iOS13. Here is my test case:

```
 Form f= new Form();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Button cameraButton = new Button();
    cameraButton.getStyle().setMargin(Label.LEFT, 5);
    cameraButton.getStyle().setMargin(Label.RIGHT, 5);
    cameraButton.setTactileTouch(true);
    cameraButton.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
    cameraButton.getPressedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
    cameraButton.getStyle().setBgColor(0xf3f3f3);
    cameraButton.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(0xececec);
    cameraButton.setHeight(20);
    cameraButton.setText("Capture Video");
    cameraButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            try {
                final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                String path = Capture.captureVideo();
                if(path != null) {
                     InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(path);
                     String strMime = "video/mp4";
                     player.setName("bla");
                        player.setDataSource(is, strMime, new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println("reset the clip for playback");
                            }
                        });
                        f.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, player);
                        f.revalidate();

                }

            }catch(Exception e) {

            }

        }
    });

    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cameraButton);
    f.show();
```

It works fine on simulator. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: There was an issue with video in iOS 13 which we fixed in the build cloud and partially with the update Apple released to 13.1. If you're experiencing a problem with older versions then I'm not sure what isn't working. Did you get the permission dialog to start recording?
If you go to the app in settings do you see video recording permissions there?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thanks for your reply.  No, I didnt get permission dialog to start recording. Even in settings I dont see video recording permission. Do I need to add any permission to make it work? The above is the code I am using to record video. And I am experiencing this issue in older version and even in iOS13.

Comment: Do you have the build hint `ios.NSCameraUsageDescription` in your project?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Yes, I have the build hint in my project, as  I am also using camera feature and its working perfectly fine. Is with video I don't get any dialog or any error.

Comment: You have an empty `catch (Exception ex){}` block.  Add some logging there to see if it throws an exception.

Comment: Copied and pasted your test case into a sample and tested it on iOS 13, and it worked fine.  Make sure you have both `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`